# Error httpUrlConnection, bufferedreader o inputStream

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Tengo una `asynctask` que recibe datos de un fichero remoto al cual accedo a través de un servlet de java. El caso es que cuando la tarea tarda un poco más porque se tiene que crear el registro en la bbdd, cuando recibo el `inputStream` con los datos del registro creado, con código 200, todo correcto, cuando llega al while para leer el buffer, casca, sin dar error ni Exception ni nada, se sale directamente del bucle y devuelve una cadena vacía porque no ha rellenado nada claro.
He probado a poner los timeout de lectura y conection pero nada. Si alguien puede ayudarme perfecto.

```
 public class ObtenerConfiguracion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    private HttpURLConnection con = null;
    private BufferedReader buffer = null;
    private StringBuffer response = null;
    private InputStreamReader miIS = null;
    private int responseCode;
    private String strResponseMsg;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    Callback callback;

    public ObtenerConfiguracion(Callback callback){
        this.callback=callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Inicio.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.txtCargarConfig));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        int apiSDK = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        String apiStr = Integer.toString(apiSDK);

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Construir los datos a enviar
            String data = "serial=" + URLEncoder.encode(Build.SERIAL,"UTF-8")+ "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(Build.DEVICE,"UTF-8")
            + "&id=" + URLEncoder.encode(Build.ID,"UTF-8") + "&brand=" + URLEncoder.encode(Build.BRAND,"UTF-8")
            + "&model=" + URLEncoder.encode(Build.MODEL,"UTF-8") + "&api=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiStr,"UTF-8");

            Log.d("HTTP", "parametros POST: " + data);

            con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // Activar método POST
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            // Tamaño previamente conocido
            con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
            // Establecer application/x-www-form-urlencoded debido a la simplicidad de los datos
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            Log.d("HTTP", "ponemos timeout");
            con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            con.setReadTimeout(60000);

            con.connect();

            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

            out.write(data.getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("HTTP", "POST Response Code : " + responseCode);

            strResponseMsg="";

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                Log.d("HTTP", "Empezamos a leer inputStream");

                String inputLine = null;
                response = new StringBuffer();

                miIS= new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
                buffer = new BufferedReader(miIS);

                //buffer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("HTTP", "inputS" + miIS.toString());
                Log.d("HTTP", "buffer" + buffer.toString());

                while ((inputLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                buffer.close();

                strResponseMsg = response.toString();

                Log.d("HTTP", strResponseMsg);

            } else {
                Log.d("HTTP", "Error en el POST: " + responseCode);
            }

        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Timeout exception");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Io exception");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Exception");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(con!=null)
                con.disconnect();
        }
        Log.d("HTTP", "hacemos return strmresponsemsg");
        return strResponseMsg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){

        callback.run(resultado);
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Aunque no dice nada os paso el Logcat para que veáis como salta directamente al return en mitad de bucle

> 03-31 18:36:28.309 10578-10792 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4 03-31 18:36:28.337 10578-10794 I/DpmTcmClient:
>   RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor 03-31
>   18:36:28.347 10578-10794 D/HTTP: ponemos timeout 03-31 18:36:36.147
>   10578-10794 D/HTTP: POST Response Code : 200 03-31 18:36:36.147
>   10578-10794 D/HTTP: Empezamos a leer inputStream 03-31 18:36:36.148
>   10578-10794 D/HTTP: inputSjava.io.InputStreamReader@1d74507 03-31
>   18:36:36.148 10578-10794 D/HTTP: bufferjava.io.BufferedReader@a1ab634
>   03-31 18:36:36.149 10578-10794 D/HTTP: hacemos return strmresponsemsg
>   03-31 18:36:36.150 10578-10578 D/callback: no recuperamos datos POST

Comment: Os pongo mejor el Logcat

Comment: El error o problema está antes del callback. Dentro de la funcion doInBanckground. Se sale del if inexplicablemente sin entrar en el while donde leo el buffer. Ni siquiera continúa despúes del while. Se sale del try y va directamente al return del doInBackground. Lo he comprobado porque me indica el Log.d("HTTP", "hacemos return strmresponsemsg");

Comment: Despues de seguir investigando el problema, el error lo tengo en que el readline() me devuelve null. He comprobado que tengo datos en el buffer pero sin embargo obtengo null. Debe tener que ver con tiempos de espera ya que solo me ocurre cuando tiene que crear el registro y tarda unos milisegundos mas. Cuando el registro ya esta creado en la BBDD recupero la informacion perfectamente. Y los datos son los mismos en cuanto a tamaño y tipo de dato. He leido algo sobre que el buffer se cae. gracias

Comment: Solucionado. Tenía un error en el servlet. Gracias